# How to use github-secret in github action workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

so I have this code:

```
name: run-script
on: push

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run script file
      run: |
         echo {here should be the secret} > ~/id_rsa
 
      shell: bash
```

On my git action, where  {here should be the secret} I want to put the variable, which is a secret token saved as a repo secret.
How can this be done?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's well-described in GitHub docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a secret named `TOKEN`, you can use it like so:

```yaml
name: run-script
on: push

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Run script file
      run: |
         echo ${{ secrets.TOKEN }} > ~/id_rsa
 
      shell: bash
```

---

Unrelated to how to use secrets, please note that `>` will override the contents of `~/id_rsa`.

Secondly, if you want to do something with your private key (which is my guess based on the filename), the correct file would be in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

And lastly, note that I have changed the checkout action to `v3` as that's the latest available version.